# In VBA, what can raise Error 438 when subcontracting?

Tags: vba, userform

Say I have this bit of code attached to a `UserForm`:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim t As String
    t = Me.Tag
    Me.Tag = Me.Caption
    Me.Caption = t
End Sub
```

That works fine. Since a similar operation will be applied to ther `UserForm`s, I tried subcontracting. In another module (not a `UserForm`), I have:

```
Public Sub swap_form_tag(ByRef frm As UserForm)
    Dim cap As String
    cap = frm.Caption
    frm.Caption = frm.Tag
    frm.Tag = cap
End Sub
```

And I then change the first event handler into:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call swap_form_tag(Me)
End Sub
```

Stepping through, I make it into `swap_form_tag` but the `frm.Caption` lookup raises error 438. What is going on?

I’ll add that if I extend the event handler with:

```
Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    Call swap_tag(ctrl)
Next ctrl
```

Where `swap_tag` is:

```
Public Sub swap_tag(ByRef ctrl As Control)
    If ctrl.Tag = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim t As String
    t = ctrl.Tag
    If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
        ctrl.Tag = ctrl.Text
        ctrl.Text = t
    ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is CommandButton Then
        ctrl.Tag = ctrl.Caption
        ctrl.Caption = t
    End If
End Sub
```

Then the `swap_tag` part works just fine. The problem seems specific to `UserForm`...

EDIT :

Indeed it seems VBA has decided that the generic `UserForm` object does not have a `Tag` property, which is a bizarre decision. Every concrete `UserForm` descendant has a `Tag`. The question then becomes How do I pass a concrete `UserForm` descendant to a subroutine so that it preserves access to its `Tag`?

Comment: What is subcontracting? You have defined a method and you are calling it.

Comment: By analogy with the business sense of the word. "A subcontractor is a person or business that undertakes to perform part or all of the obligations of another's contract." (Wikipedia). Here I wrote a sub which will perform part of the work of other subs and functions (because one always wants to avoid writing the same code again and again).

Comment: You probably don't want to invent new terms for these things, they have names already. Here you created a "subroutine" in order to "encapsulate" certain logic.

Answer (score 2):

The `UserForm` base class does not have a property `Tag`.
Your concrete `SomeSpecificUserForm` does, but the generic `UserForm` does not. Same for the `Name`.

So you will have to define your method as `Public Sub swap_form_tag (ByVal frm As Object)`.

Comment: Doesn't `UserForm` descend from `Object`?

Comment: It does. Why?..

Comment: If a descendant, then how come it does not inherit the Tag property?

Comment: `Object` does not have it either.

Comment: Why did you suggest that as a solution then? The subroutine would not work at all. It needs to swap Tag and Caption.

Comment: I suggested it as a solution because it will work, which you would have noticed if you tried it. You may want to read up on your basics, the search term is "late binding", an example result is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients#late-binding.

Comment: It does indeed work. It boggles the mind: why does late binding work with `Object` but not with `UserForm`?

Comment: Because with `UserForm` you get early binding, so the presence of the methods and properties being accessed is checked at compile time, and the compiler refuses to proceed because there is no `Tag` property declared in the `UserForm` class. With `Object` you get late binding, and the presence of properties and methods is not checked at all. So when the call to `Tag` is executed against the concrete form instance (which is bigger than its base class `UserForm`), it is able to satisfy it.