# Access.Form issues using CallByName in MS Access (also how to get Inter-form Communication working)

Tags: vba, ms-access

The background here is that I've been periodically attempting to implement a nice generic method for communication between non-modal, pop-up access forms and their calling form (why is basically because I want to be able to interact with other pop-up forms at the same time). This is my latest attempt using CallByName, which looked promising, however I've run into a head-scratcher to do with classes that I don't understand. I'm fully prepared to be told that I'm barking up the wrong tree here if anyone has a better/simpler proposal.

This is a purely contrived pared-down example. I've got two forms, a Base Form and a Popup Form, the latter created by the former. The Popup form is non-modal and once it is created and initialised by the Base Form the pop-up looks after itself.

In this case I've tried to save a reference to the Baseform at initialisation and also a return function to invoke thinking I could use CallByName when the popup is done doing its thing. And it actually works... kind of. It works perfectly provide I explicitly define the form variable type as the specific type of the Base form rather than Access.Form and this seems... odd to me. Why should this matter and is there a simple way around it. I'd like this particular popup to be a generic form that can be called by several 'Base forms' so would rather not have to explicitly define the Form type. so... I don't know what's going wrong here, is this a bug, by design, am I doing something dumb, should I be I don't know, dynamically casting to the baseform before running CallByName first (is that even something I can do).

Interested in any insights anyone has here to what's going on and what I can do about it. (Or if I should just go try something completely different) I can see more than a few SO posts about CallByName so maybe this is just an unreliable path to tread..

I'll Include the code modules for the two forms below.. The forms themselves are just trivial with a button on each to invoke the code.

**Form_frmBaseForm**

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdOpenForm_Click()

    Dim frmNew As Form_frmPopupForm

    Set frmNew = New Form_frmPopupForm

    ' Feed popup form return data
    frmNew.Init Me.Form, "ReturnFunction"
    frmNew.Visible = True

    ' Set it free.
    Set frmNew = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "End of Base Form Code"
    
End Sub

Public Function ReturnFunction()
    
    ' Do something here...
    MsgBox "I've been told the popup form closed!"
    
End Function
```

**Form_frmPopupForm**

```
Option Compare Database

Private frm As Access.Form

' Generic type fails
Private frmRet As Access.Form
' Explicit type for Form works!
Private expfrmRet As Form_frmBaseForm

Private fnRet As String

Public Sub Init(frmReturn As Form, fnReturn As String)

    ' Self Persist Form!
    Set frm = Me.Form
    
    ' Save calling form info and function
    Set frmRet = frmReturn
    Set expfrmRet = frmReturn
    
    fnRet = fnReturn
    
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCloseForm_Click()
    Me.Visible = False
    'check for existence
        If Not expfrmRet Is Nothing Then
            ' This works
            CallByName expfrmRet, fnRet, VbMethod
            ' Fails with Error 2465
            CallByName frmRet, fnRet, VbMethod
        Else
            MsgBox "Originally calling form is gone"
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `works perfectly provide I explicitly define the form variable type as the specific type of the Base form rather than Access.Form` - and what happens when you provide an Access.Form, and how do you provide it?

Comment: @Nick Have you considered using events instead of using `CallByName`? Your `Form_frmPopupForm` could emit an event that `Form_frmBaseForm` could listen to, avoiding this situation entirely.

Comment: @ErikA It isn't an interface, it's a base class. That is not the question I asked though.

Comment: @ErikA `Are you sure?` - the ODL in MSACC.OLB declares `coclass Form {
        [default] dispinterface _Form3;
        [, source] interface _FormEvents;
        [default, source] dispinterface _FormEvents2;
    }`, so it must be. And if it wasn't, where all the default functionality would come from when you'd create an empty Form of yours? It's not about "providing an interface", it's about declaring a variable to store the object, which indeed [can make a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77539332/11683).

Comment: @GSerg Thanks, I've learned something new, apologies for my misinformed comments, cleaning them up!

Comment: @GSerg apologies I left that part of the explanation buried in comments in my code. What I'm doing is passing the Base Form to the Popup form through the Init function and then assigning it to an Access.Form type variable within he Popup form. Then when I go to use it in CallByName I'm unable to call the ReturnFunction function I've defined  and instead get a 2465 Error code "Application-defined or object-defined error". When I assign the passed base form to an explicitly typed Form_frmBaseForm object then magically it works

Comment: @ErikA I think using events would probably be great and possibly a lot simpler/more consistent.  I've possibly misunderstood some of the documentation I've read somewhere about events in access forms being a bit unreliable and have prematurely discarded the idea.  I've not written my own event code before (beyond using that already baked in) so I'm not quite clear on the correct process in Access. Could you suggest any good examples or some decent documentation?

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for that link, I read through the UserForm/Object Early/Late binding example, and can understand how that would make a difference, but my example seems to be an issue at runtime rather than compile time. I did try as bit of a 'HailMary' by converting the Init paramater and fmRet type to Object, but it still gives me the same error. It's interesting. It's like CallByName is doing some sort of 'pre-check' on whether the function call is a valid one for that class, but is only referencing the variable class rather than the actual object class.

Comment: @GSerg If I do a typename(frmRet) while debugging I get the 'right' class Form_frmBaseForm

Comment: @ErikA oh wow, ok so looks like that was just the nudge I needed. I pushed my google-fu a bit harder and finally found some decent examples of custom event handling in access (mostly I was ending up with tutorials on how to use the built in events).  This walkthrough was outstanding [link](https://nolongerset.com/raising-custom-events-in-vba/) and I've already built a working example that does what it's supposed to and is far more elegant than what I was trying to hack together using CallByName.

Comment: @GSerg I'm still curious about any insights into what's going on with CallByName or what I'm 'doing wrong' in my original post, but for now I'll post my example event based code as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ErikA for pointing me in the direction of Events, this seems like a much simpler and more elegant way of achieving the type of inter form communication I was looking for. I recommend the [tutorial covered here at no longer set](https://nolongerset.com/raising-custom-events-in-vba/) for those interested as a starter.

Below is the completely overhauled code changed from the above. Rather than the Baseform 'informing' the popupform how to 'get back in touch', the Baseform maintains a reference to the popup form and listens out for a specific close event. This also has the benefit of giving me a reasonably tidy  mechanism for sending data back to the baseform.

**Form_frmBaseFormEV**

```
Option Compare Database

Private WithEvents frmPop1 As Form_frmPopupFormEV

Private Sub cmdOpenForm_Click()
    Set frmPop1 = New Form_frmPopupFormEV
    frmPop1.Visible = True
    MsgBox "End of Base Form Code"
End Sub

Private Sub frmPop1_FormIsClosed()
    MsgBox "Form Closed With No Data"
End Sub

Private Sub frmPop1_FormIsClosedWithValue(sData As String)
    MsgBox "Form Closed With Data Value: " & sData
End Sub
```

**Form_frmPopupFormEV**

```
Option Compare Database

Public Event FormIsClosed()
Public Event FormIsClosedWithValue(sData As String)

Private Sub cmdCloseForm_Click()
    Me.Visible = False
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtData1) Then
        RaiseEvent FormIsClosedWithValue(Me.txtData1)
    Else
        RaiseEvent FormIsClosed
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Also.. *txtData1* is just a simple unbound text field on the popup form and the double events are probably redundant, could just as easily have a single event and test for a null I suppose, I was just playing around.

Comment: Yep, much cleaner. Personally I'd go for a single event with a nullable data-type, e.g. Variant. The subscriber would then check if null and act accordingly.